# Is this use of the subjunctive mood correct?

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood

I've read this sentence to myself quite a few times now and it seems the more I do so the less correct it sounds. I think it's using the subjunctive mood, however I'm not sure if I've used it correctly. Can anyone say if this is right or not?

> bla bla bla... and it is our hope that anyone be able to receive healthcare without having to compromise on ... bla bla.

More specifically, I'm concerned about using "be" in its simple/infinitive form, it doesn't seem to sound right to me, should I have used "should"?

Comment: What fools these mortals be!

Comment: The verb *hope* doesn't usually take the subjunctive. You could use *is, will be* or *would be*.

Comment: You’re quite right, that is a subjunctive construction (some linguists will say that the subjunctive doesn’t exist in English and would call the construction something else; but the concept is the same). That said, it does sound off to me too, even substituting the indicative. I think it’s because _be_ is the wrong verb in essence here—your hope is that anyone should _if you have your way become_ able to receive healthcare, and the subjunctive _be_ doesn’t quite fit that. @GEdgar That’s _not_ a subjunctive, simply an old-fashioned plural form.

Comment: Thanks Janus! Do you think "can" would do the trick? ...and it is our hope that anyone can receive healthcare without having to compromise on....

Comment: I don't think "should become able" is right. Hope points to an as yet unrealized future here. To wit: It is my hope you will be able to do the work.//It is my hope anyone will be able to receive healthcare.//The present can be used in some circumstances also. It is my hope you are able to do the work. [present meaning]

Comment: @Peter: But "hope" here is a noun, not a verb. I can't see that the subjunctive is particularly unusual in such contexts, except for the fact that OP's example only really works for me if I replace ***anyone*** with ***everyone***. Not that I can find written instances with the specific word ***hope***, but [here are some examples](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22desire+that+everyone+be+able+to%22) of *[people having the] **desire** that everyone be able to [do something]*.

Comment: Yes. That was my thought, too. The whole thing is a mess and they need to start over again with less pompous phraseology. That's if anybody is sposta get any information out of it. It's already a dead loss for morale, and one suspects it's strictly CYA material pasted together out of leftovers by someone with a tin ear.

Comment: Surely it's not that much of a pompous dead loss is it John? I wouldn't have expected a bit of the subjunctive mood to throw off your average reader.

Comment: After all this my sentence sounds a lot better, I don't see any problem with the subjunctive mood following an expression of hope, I can't find a hard and fast list of verbs that the subjunctive should follow, only recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sentence is fine if you want to sound idealistic.  And there's nothing wrong with sounding idealistic.

Comment: @Anthony - In case you don't know how it works yet: if you want to show your support for an answer, you click on the upward-pointing triangle to the left of an answer.  For the opposite, you'd click on the downward triangle underneath.  If you don't feel thumbs up or thumbs down about an answer, you don't click on either.

Comment: Thanks, it's just that votes cast by those with less than 15 reputations are not publicly displayed. I need a few more.

Comment: @Anthony - Oh.  Okay, I looked into it.  Apparently one needs a rep of 15 to be able to upvote an answer.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges.  However, I have not found anything to indicate that a minimum rep is needed to accept an answer.  n fact, I believe 2 rep points are awarded when you accept an answer.  (However, obviously, if you do not find any acceptable answers to your question, then you should not accept one.)

Comment: You can also provide feedback and ask for improvements to a promising answer.  And if you see a particularly helpful comment, you can request that it be converted to an answer.